# What is the difference between class variables and member variables in Java

Tags: java, variables

There is not much to explain. The title is enough to explain the question. I got this on an interview today.

```
What are class variables and member variables in Java?
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't work there.

Comment: What did you answer? And what did they say when you did?

Comment: I'm pretty sure by `class variables` they mean *static* class variables, while with `member variables` they mean... well, *non-static* class variables.

Comment: Actually that was written exam before interview. And my answer was quite funny.

Comment: @Zhuinden Can you explain? Why you think so?

Comment: Class variable is class-specific while member variable is instance-specific. Something like that. I think that is what they meant.

Comment: @TimB I had no idea. But I wrote attributes are member variables and objects and instances of a class are class variables. :D

Comment: As already some have said, my thoughts are: class variables are static variables and member variables are instance variables.

Comment: I'd mark that wrong. class variables have the scope of the class and can be used for the lifetime of the class when it is instantiated. Member variables are within the scope of the containing method and only have a lifetime of when the method is called and ran.

Comment: @Luminous no member variables are within the scope of the object created from the class, not method because that would be local variables.

Comment: @Omoro then that would mean they are one in the same...they were probably referring to static and non-static variables. Like what Zhuinden said.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I never did :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Zhuinden said they probably meant static variables instead of class variables. For member variables, an instance of the class is needed in order to access the variable. For example if I had a class Foo, and it had a member variable int bar, the only way I could access it is by doing something like

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
doSomething(foo.bar);
```

However, if I have bar was a static variable, that means that I can access it even though I don't have an instance of the object. I would access it like this:

```
doSomething(Foo.bar)
```

without having to create an instance of Foo.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_variable#Static_member_variables_and_static_member_functions)

Comment: Should we go for __probably__ ?

Comment: Yes, see this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_variable#Static_member_variables_and_static_member_functions

Comment: "probably" will be the best you'll get unless you ask the person that designed the test. "class variable" and "member variable" aren't defined in the JLS so you there's no final instance to say what's correct.

Answer (score 2):

A member variable is one per object, every object has its own copy of instance variable while a class variable is one per Class, every object of that class shares the same class variable..

A class variable also called as static variable is initialized when the JVM loads the class probably take an example static block if there is no main method in your program while this is not the case with your member variables.

Class variables should be used when you don't want to have copy for each instance while
member variables should be used when you want separate copy for each instance of object.

From point of garbage collection class variables have a long life as class variables are associated with the class and not individual instance.
class variables are cleaned up when the ClassLoader which hold the class unloaded. This is very rare..while in case of member variables they get cleaned up when the instance is cleaned up. Hope this helps.